# C++ - Read from either file or in-memory buffer with the same function

Tags: c++, c

Is there a single standard C/C++ function which takes either a file handle/pointer or a pointer to an in-memory buffer and reads data from the file/buffer?

I have a function which pulls data from a file, performs operations on said data, and sends it out over a socket. I also have a function that takes data in the form of a char buffer, performs exactly the same operations on that data, and sends it over a socket. This problem isn't that hard. I just thought it would be convenient if there was a function like

```
read(void *dest, void *src, int src_type, size_t amount)
```

Comment: The answers for C and C++ would be different.

Comment: You could use `memory mapped file`, and implement only the pointer version of the function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I could use either C or C++ functions. If any such function exists in C or C++, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: I don't think you have thought it through... that parameter src_type, why would it be an improvement to tell the type of function by way of a parameter, as opposed to call different functions?

Comment: You could implement the memory function yourself in a handful of lines of code. And your function above with src_type too. Besides, how would the "read" function know when the src buffer is empty?  You would have to add a size argument. Basically, for C, the question makes little sense, especially because the same function name can not have multiple signatures.

Comment: @Prof.Falken That's a fair point. I didn't want to write a function with a switch on src_type in it. It seemed ugly. That's why I was hoping for either an existing function like that, or for a couple of existing functions with which I could write my own read without the src_type, and in only a few lines.

Comment: @ztforster, if you can use memory mapped files but must use C, then you have an abstraction right there. Always use array manipulation in that case, no `open()`/`read()` etc.. If you have C++, you can use dasblinkenlights solution.

Comment: You should be able to do it, but I would add C and C++ #defines if you are compiling the code on different systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ you can use [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/istream) as an abstraction on top of a file with an [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) implementation, or an in-memory buffer with an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) implementation.

The beauty of this approach is that your function does not need to know about the implementation type, because receiving the argument by reference would be sufficient:

```
void readData(std::istream& in_data) {
    ...
}
```

The caller would then construct an appropriate implementation, and pass it to `readData`.

Comment: Impressive answer - and C++ is the only language it makes sense to answer in. For C, it just doesn't work without making the "solution" more convoluted than just using two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the `operator>>()` on an input stream (`std::istream`), which can either be a filestream, a iostream or a stringstream

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about windows but it will work in Linux.

```
void readif(int fd ,char *src,size_t nbytes){
   read(fd,src,nbytes);
   //error handler code
   //Other stuffs 
}

int fd = open(file);
//for std::input fd = 0 
//for in memory data use mmap
```

[mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)
[open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)
[read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)